# Python 3 OpenCV Functions and Tkinter

Tags: opencv, python-3.x, tkinter

OpenCV's WaitKey() and destroyAllWindows() function doesnot work with tKinter properly. Each works well then delete the other one.

```
def function():
    #do some processes
    #show the result images with cv2.namedWindow, cv2.resizeWindow and then cv2.imshow
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("blabla")
root.geometry("200x200")
button = tk.Button(root, text = "Button", command = function)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What you trying to make ? WaitKey and destroyAllwindows for cv2 namedWindow. And why you use tkinter ?

Comment: My OpenCV function shows an image. Then I created a button to run that function with tKinter. When i clicked button, openCV function works and shows the image. Then i want to close image window(which is pop-up) with anykey.

Actually there are many images and i want to close all of them at once